# Compare all columns between 2 rows in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to compare all columns between two rows in a table using php/mysqli but just can't figure out how to do it. My table looks something like:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
| username | compare1 | compare2 | compare3 | compare4 | compare5 etc |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
| Adam     |        1 |        0 |        1 |        1 |            0 |
| Billy    |        1 |        1 |        1 |        1 |            0 |
| Charlie  |        1 |        0 |        0 |        1 |            1 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

I want to select say username Charlie as the child and username Adam as the parent then compare their values for all other columns (there's quite a few) in the table. If any of the child values is 0 where the parent value is 1 then the query returns false, otherwise, it returns true.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select (count(*) = 0) as flag
from t tp join
     t tc
     on tp.username = 'Adam' and tc.username = 'Charlie'
where (0, 1) in ( (tp.compare1, tc.compare1), (tp.compare2, tc.compare2),
                  . . .
                );
```

Note:  This assumes that each `username` has only one row.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative query could be:

```
select c.compare1 >= p.compare1
   and c.compare2 >= p.compare2
   and c.compare3 >= p.compare3
   and c.compare4 >= p.compare4
   and c.compare5 >= p.compare5
   as res
from mytable p
   , mytable c
where p.username = 'Adam'
  and c.username = 'Charlie';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b51672/2